# Missing core.lua installing redis-lua for lua5.1

Tags: lua, redis

I'm trying to install a redis client for Lua5.1, any client will do.

I installed **redis-lua**(https://github.com/nrk/redis-lua) 
and 
**LuaSocket**(http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/),

But when I try to get a "redis.connect" in my lua script, it says "could not find module "socket.core" .

And I find that there is no core.lua under */usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket* directory, how should I solve this?

p.s. I'v tried many redis clients for lua, and because I'm not familia with lua and luarocks, non of them works, always missing some dependencies that I cannot find, or got error when compiling with gcc.

Comment: How are you running the Lua script?

Comment: `socket.core` is a C module. How did you install luasocket?

Comment: I installed luasocket from source code

Comment: @Itamar lua script.lua in shell